# Redux upgrade is causing invariant violation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am getting the invariant violation error in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2x4v68mq7r):

> Invariant Violation Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: object.
>
> Check the render method of `Provider`.

[This codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ll677jnw6l) worked without any issues. It is exactly the same except that instead of using redux 6.0 and `connected-react-router` it uses redux 5.0.6 and `react-router-redux`.

What could be wrong with this upgrade, or something else that I am doing, that is causing this error? Thanks! You can see some code samples below as well.

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { ConnectedRouter } from "connected-react-router";
import { fetchStuff } from "./actions/index";
import App from "./components/app";
import { store, history } from "./store";

store.dispatch(fetchStuff);

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

**App.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const App = ({ data }) => (
  <div>{data.length > 0 ? <h1>Completed</h1> : <h1>Loading</h1>}</div>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  data: state.data.data
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `codesandbox`, `react` and `react-dom` are both having different verisons, you need to use the same version of react and react-dom in your project. Upgrade **react-dom to 16.4.0** in your codesandbox and it works

[Working Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5ypxrnyz5k)